# Use Gitlab API to create variables on project

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I am trying to create a GitLab variable for a project on GitLab using a cURL command.

I am following the API and the relevant paragraph [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/instance_level_ci_variables.html#create-instance-variable).
Looking at the example on the docs, I cannot find any evidence on how Gitlab knows which repo I am trying to add the variable to.

I tried adding a private token and runnnig the command and I ended up with a 403.

Could someone please explain how to use the GitLab API to add variables to a repo through a cURL command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Looking at the example on the docs, I cannot find any evidence on how Gitlab knows which repo I am trying to add the variable to

But... the all idea behind "instance-level" variables is to be "global", not tied to a specific project.

See [issue 14108](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/14108):

> ## Global (instance-level) variables for CI builds
>
> Less of an issue or more or a feature/question perhaps ... It would nice to support global variables in the CI builds; classic use-case being deployment keys / docker registry credentials.
>
> ### Problem to solve
>
> Without support for global variables users must manually enter the same credentials repeatedly for dozens of projects when migrating to GitLab for details like:
>
> - docker private registry credentials
> - kubernetes credentials)
> - deployment keys
>
> ### Proposal
>
> Implement support for global (instance-level) variables for CI builds by:
>
> - Re-use the refactor/re-design of CI variables in project/group settings
> - Place under CI/CD section in the admin settings

A better API for your case would be:

> ### [Create variable (project](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/project_level_variables.html#create-variable)
>
> ```sh
> curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" \
>     "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/1/variables" \ 
>     --form "key=NEW_VARIABLE" --form "value=new value"
> ```

Comment: this worked for me perfectly, thanks for the answer! I was looking in the wrong place.

Comment: I have one more follow up on this - would it be possible to add multiple variables using the Gitlab API? or do I need to make multiple POST requests for this?

Comment: @berlin From what I see, you would need multiple POST.